# Set a field value to ID value

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm normalizing my database, to I'm trying to set the value of a field the same as the ID for that row so I can join tables.

I tried using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, but it doesn't work. I don't get a error, but I only get zeros.

```
INSERT INTO `eleves` (`user_id`, 
`first_name`, `last_name`, 
`username`, `groupe`, 
`password`, `courriel`, 
`active`, `auteur`, 
`citations`, `absurde`, 
`vocabulaire`,  `analyse`, 
`themes`, `personnages`) 
VALUES (NULL, 
'Jane', 'Doe', 
'janedoe', '400', 
'password', 'jane@doe.com', 
'1', LAST_INSERT_ID(), 
LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID(), 
LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID(), 
LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *empty field*? To my knowledge it should be inserting a zero.

Comment: I played with it, and now get zeros. But this is still not what I'm trying to insert... I posted the full code.

Comment: What query will require you to have the same information in several fields?

Comment: I also have an `auteur`, `citations`, `absurde`... and so on table, and I'm joining those. So I need the IDs to make, don't I?

Comment: @Sarah Could you show the definition of one of these other tables (auteur, citations, ...) as well?  What is the relationship between the table eleves and the other tables (i.e. one-to-many or many-to-one)? If you want to join the other tables to eleves based on the corresponding field in eleves, you can as well use the ID field directly. If you want the fields auteur, citations etc to be foreign keys to the corresponding tables, last_insert_id() will not give the correct IDs as you will have to collect these IDs as you insert into the other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, during your MySQL session there happened no auto generated id was inserted. And hence for the fields for which you want to fill `last_insert_id()` must be a `zero` but not an `empty`(NULL?, SPACE?).

Try to define a primary key with auto increment in your table and let your generate a new record. And see what happens !

See the following example:

```
$ mysql -u ravi -p test
Enter password: ********
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2 to server version: 5.0.22-community-nt

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table eleves( user_id int not null auto_increment primary key, username varchar(10), auteur int, citations int, absurde int );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into eleves( username, auteur, citations, absurde )
    -> values( 'janedoe1', last_insert_id(), last_insert_id(), last_insert_id() );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from eleves;
+---------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
| user_id | username | auteur | citations | absurde |
+---------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
|       1 | janedoe1 |      0 |         0 |       0 |
+---------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into eleves( username, auteur, citations, absurde )
    -> values( 'janedoe2', last_insert_id(), last_insert_id(), last_insert_id() );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from eleves;
+---------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
| user_id | username | auteur | citations | absurde |
+---------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
|       1 | janedoe1 |      0 |         0 |       0 |
|       2 | janedoe2 |      1 |         1 |       1 |
+---------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Still not working... I gave up and found another way around. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

remove the single quotes around them

```
INSERT INTO `eleves`(`user_id`, `username`, `auteur`, `citations`, `absurde`) 
VALUES (NULL,'janedoe',LAST_INSERT_ID(),LAST_INSERT_ID(),LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I actually removed them when I tried to execute it, but somehow I put them back when posting it. Edited my question. It still does not work.

Comment: so what's the problem? it seems it's working on [SQLFiddle (click here)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99e3b/1).

Comment: Somehow, it is not working when I use the full query (my table is a lot bigger). [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efc07) 

    INSERT INTO `eleves` (`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `groupe`, `password`, `courriel`, `active`, `auteur`, `citations`, `absurde`, `vocabulaire`, `analyse`, `themes`, `personnages`) VALUES (NULL, 'Jane', 'Doe', 'janedoe', '400', 'password', 'jane@doe.com', '1', LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID());